# Cannot set creation time when a file is on a removable disk

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

I try to set Creation, Write and Access time for all files in a directory. And that works if file is on local machine. But when I try to do it for directory on a removable disk, I get an exception:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The parameter is incorrect. : '**path**'

I really don't know why it happens, but:

- the path is correct
- BitLocker is turned off
- files don't have a read-only attribute

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var files = new DirectoryInfo(args[0]).GetFiles();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        File.SetCreationTime(file.FullName, new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
        File.SetLastAccessTime(file.FullName, new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
        File.SetLastWriteTime(file.FullName, new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
    }
}
```

I'll be grateful for your help.

Comment: If you set a newer date this will work (for example: ```new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)```)  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown because a filesystem on my flash drive is **FAT**. And the FAT file system counts dates from *1/1/1980*.